# javassist - ClassNotFoundException using a custom Translator

Tags: classnotfoundexception, bytecode, loader, javassist

I have two classes in my `test` package: `Bean`, `Demo2` and `VerboseLoader`.

`Bean.java`:

```
package test;

public class Bean {
}
```

`VerboseLoader.java`:

```
package test;

import javassist.CannotCompileException;
import javassist.ClassPool;
import javassist.NotFoundException;
import javassist.Translator;

public class VerboseLoader implements Translator{

    @Override
    public void start(ClassPool pool) throws NotFoundException, CannotCompileException {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoad(ClassPool pool, String classname) throws NotFoundException, CannotCompileException {
        System.out.println("onLoad called for " + classname);
    }
}
```

`Demo2.java`:

```
package test;

import javassist.*;

public class Demo2{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        if(args.length >= 1){
            Translator translator = new VerboseLoader();
            ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
            Loader loader = new Loader(pool);
            loader.addTranslator(pool, translator);

            String[] pargs = new String[args.length-1];
            System.arraycopy(args, 1, pargs, 0, pargs.length);

            loader.run(args[0], pargs);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Main args...");
        }
    }

}
```

will throw

```
onLoad called for Bean
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Bean
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    at javassist.Loader.delegateToParent(Loader.java:431)
    at javassist.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:311)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    at javassist.Loader.run(Loader.java:284)
    at test.Demo2.main(Demo2.java:21)
```

*[Javassist 3.23.1-GA]*

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've missed the package name before the className

```
loader.run("test."+args[0], pargs);
```